# doing a data analysis project in R, keep getting error "Error: Must request at least one colour from a hue palette"

Tags: r, data-analysis

looked all over the internet, couldn't find anything comparable to what exactly I am trying to do. any help would be appreciated thank you!!

I am making grouped histograms and density plots for variables pertaining to heart rate and age. this is what I have to make a grouped histogram and density plot:

```
heart_disease$Age_cat[heart_disease$Age>= 18 & heart_disease$Age<= 35]= "young adult"
heart_disease$Age_cat[heart_disease$Age>= 36 & heart_disease$Age<= 55]= "middle adult"
heart_disease$Age_cat[heart_disease$Age>= 56 & heart_disease$Age<= 65]= "older adult"
heart_disease$Age_cat[heart_disease$Age>= 66 & heart_disease$Age<= 110]= "elderly adult"

ggplot(heart_disease, aes(x = HeartDisease, fill = Age_cat)) + geom_histogram(colour = "black", binwidth = .1, lwd = .75, linetype= 1,position = "identity", alpha = 4,) + labs(x = "HeartDisease", y = "Frequency", title = "Distribution of Heart Disease by Age")

Densityplot <- ggplot(data = heart_disease,aes(x=HeartDisease,fill= Age_cat ))+ geom_density(alpha = 0.7,cex=1)+ggtitle(labs(title = "Distribution of Heart Disease by Age"))+theme(text = element_text(size=10))
Densityplot
```

error message reads: `Error: Must request at least one colour from a hue palette`.

originally I hadn't listed my variables as "Age_cat", just "age" and it worked fine. My partner told me we have to list with _cat and now nothing I've done works. this is what I originally had for example and that ran and created a plot, although quite funky looking of a plot.

```
heart_disease$Age[heart_disease$Age>= 18 & heart_disease$Age<= 35]= "young adult"
```

*I'm still learning to read these plots plz be nice I'm trying:)

Comment: please format your question

Comment: @moth I am sorry. I am also still learning this website.

Comment: if you can provide a reproducible example as well, people will be able to help you much quicker.

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example